# How to read data from local XML file in Flex

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a java web application which contains a flash part.Currently the `.swf` file is reading the `xml` file from project `src` folder. I want to access the `xml` file from local file system(in `C:/` drive ).How to access XML data from `C:/` drive.Currently my java web application is accessing the same `xml` file from `C:/` drive.Can i pass the `xml` data through javascript to `.swf` file.
Is it a best practice.Which is the best practice for accessing XML file from local file system in Flex.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your swf is in a web application, you can't access freely the hard drive. There are nevertheless two options:

### FileReference

With the command [`FileReference.browse()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29), you can allow the user to choose a file from the local system and load it, or upload it.
If you choose to `load` it, you'll have access to its `data` as a `ByteArray`.

### ExternalInterface

ExternalInterface allows you to communicate via javascript with the browser. You can set a responder with [`ExternalInterface.addCallback()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29). Check the [reference for some example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Comment: thanks for the answer.can i pass contents of xml as a parameter to swfobject.embedSWF()

Comment: In the example you should use `thisMovie("ExternalInterfaceExample").sendToActionScript(value);` but yes, you just have to send it as a String.
And with swfobject I don't see why you couldn't send the XML as a string as a paramter. Note that, with this method, you can only do that before the swf creation, not after.

Answer (score 0):

You say this is a Java web application. So one way would be to put the XML file on server and then make a service call to read it in Flex.

```
var httpService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
httpService.url = path; //The URL of the XML file goes here
httpService.resultFormat = "e4x";
httpService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, onFaultHttpService);
httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onResultHttpService);
httpService.send();
```

You will have to define the `onFaultHttpService` and `onResultHttpService` methods.

AFAIK, there is no way to access the filesystem directly in Flex, unless you are using AIR.

Comment: my java web application is on server and XML file is inside C: drive in Server.Is it possible to access.if so how to specify path.

Comment: By "putting it on the server", I mean you could, (if possible), copy the xml file to your WebContent directory in the Java web project. (Your swf file will probably also be in this directory). You will then be able to access the xml file using a URL rather than a filesystem path.

Comment: now the XML is in src folder in web project.but the requirement is to access xml from C: Drive.

Comment: Just saw your updated question. That makes my answer invalid :) But like I said, there is no direct way to access the filesystem in a Flex web application. My intuition tells me that what you're doing is not a good approach. But it largely depends on what you're trying to accomplish.